# regexp-filter just searches headlines (org agenda view)

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, filtering

I have a problem with the filtering function `org-agenda-filter-by-regexp`:

It just searches the headlines of the entries not the whole entry text.

Example:

```
 * title :work:
 text
```

Searching for the tag 'work' gives the correct and only headline 'title' in the 'Org Agenda' buffer. But after the regexp-filtering with (= text) the headline disappears because(?) 'text' isn't part of the headline.

I know I can start with the function for 'Search for keywords' (usually C-c a s) and then filter by the tag 'work' but mostly I start with tag searching and then look for keywords.

The [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Filtering_002flimiting-agenda-items.html) says:
"only show agenda **entries** matching the regular expression the user entered."
But it seems that it searches only the **headlines** of the entries.

---

EDIT: Not a solution, just a suggestion. Maybe it helps somebody. If you want to search for a keyword "text" and you know it will have to many results you can add the tag as an additional *keyword*: `:work:` -- but in this case only the direct tag of the headline can be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

"Entry" is used ambiguously in the documentation:

- an Org mode entry consists of a headline, scheduling information, optional drawers and the body of entry (text, possibly followed by subentries).
- an agenda entry consists of some agenda information (the category, scheduling information, possibly some other things controlled by the variable `org-agenda-prefix-format`) and the headline from an Org mode entry.

IOW, the agenda does not display the full Org mode entry, just its headline, so there is no way to search directly the agenda buffer for text that occurs in the body of an Org mode entry.

But you can use `C-c a /` to use `org-occur-in-agenda-files` to search for text using a regular expression in all the files that the agenda uses, i.e. all the files in `org-agenda-files`.

EDIT: Try using a tag search (`C-c a m <tag> RET`) and then in the resulting buffer do `M-x org-search-view RET {<regexp>} RET` and see if that works for you. If it does, you might want to add a binding for `org-search-view` in the `org-agenda-mode-map` to make it easier to invoke - there is is very little left free, but `Z` was not defined in my case, so I use it here as an example:

```el
(define-key org-agenda-mode-map (kbd "Z") #'org-search-view)
```

With this key binding, the work flow would be: `C-c a m <tag> RET Z {<regexp>} RET`.

EDIT 2: Unfortunately, as the OP points out in a comment, this does not work: the `org-search-view` is done from scratch, not in the context of the previous tag search.

Comment: Thanks. But as I mentioned I need the power of tags and the keywords. `C-c a /` is just for keywords.

Comment: Edited to add a possible workflow. I'd be interested to find out whether it works for you.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean: Of course it will work but it isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry - I never pushed the edit. *Now* see if that workflow makes sense and whether it works.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It starts a *new* agenda search - it ignores the tag search before.